# Sending emails using Gmail works locally but not on heroku (django)

Tags: python, django, email

Sending an email works locally with this settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER_PASSWORD")
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
```

However, when I try this live on Heroku I get this error:

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /password_reset/
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError p80sm1777250qke.19 - gsmtp', 'None')
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how to correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already found a solution to this. I did have the same issue recently. I actually sought and find help.

1. First you need to grant access to a less secure application to your google account (I believe you already do since you mentioned it works locally.)
2. Test if Google did not automatically close access to the less secure application if not the case: you will need to clean Captcha by going to:
   https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

See detail at: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/32840224?hl=en

3. Remember to put the environment variables on Heroku as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

my English is not the best i will try to explain what worked for me.
so I tried these solutions and did not work :

1. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha ,
2. grant access to a less secure application
3. to create an app-specific password for less secure apps
4. environment variables were working in python
5. no misspelling mistakes with password or email

*solutions*

change the names of environment variables identical to those ones in settings.py
so instead of doing
**EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")**

change to

**EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_HOST_USER")**
and also same for your password.

before i did my solution above i had tried with simple strings and also works
**EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email'** and
**EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'**

after i did my solutions i had to do 1) https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha